# C++: What is an alternative to system(...) that is cross platform and safe?

Tags: c++, linux, cross-platform, system, executable

I'd like to use `system(...)` in C++ to execute another executable files. After some research, it seems that everyone thinks `system(...)` is the worst thing ever, and no one should use it unless they absolutely have to, because it is

- resource heavy
- not guaranteed to work on all platforms
- anti-virus software often considers it malicious
- can be easily exploited / can unintentionally launch the wrong programs

So, is there an alternative to `system(...)` that I should use? I am on Linux, but I would like it to be cross-platform (at least between Linux and Windows).

Comment: For cross-platform working, `system()` is portable (it is standard C, and therefore also standard C++). Any alternative is platform-specific. The 'not guaranteed to work on all platforms' comment is odd; it isn't clear what point is being made. If you compose a complex command line with lots of metacharacters (I/O redirection, quotes, etc), then you limit the chances of the command working across platforms. But for simple commands with simple arguments, it will work OK. As to launching the wrong programs, that depends on how you build the command name, but the details are platform-specific.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so do you think it would be okay for me to just use `system()`? Does it decrease performance of the launched application?

Comment: `system` is NOT portable; it is entirely possible (and ok) for it to be disregarded, for it to execute differently on different platforms, and for various ill side effects to occur! It is invoking the "command processor", which very well may not exist (for example, on embedded systems).

Comment: @Alice but what if I know that all the platforms I will be working with have the command processor?

Comment: @gragas: It depends on what you're planning to do. If you simply intend to run a simple program with simple arguments, and you make sure that's what you do (by validating any user input, and the environment too), then you can use `system()`. The alternative is to create a more appropriate interface, and implement it separately for each platform — containing the portability to the code that operates as (more or less) a surrogate for `system()`. However, you'd need to define that interface carefully. For example, you might decide to use `int alt_system(char **argv);` instead of a single string.

Comment: @gragas You can't know that; it's not part of the C specification or requirements. And that doesn't deal with the filesystem requirements, the different kinds of command processors (dash vs bash is a good example, and let's not even get started on powershell). None of these are in any way "portable". While `system` may work, for trivial examples, across trivial platform differences, it should never be regarded in any way as portable.

Comment: @gragas: note that there's a fair chance that you'll have to tailor the text submitted to `system()` to conform to the expectations of the system on which it is running.  You won't be able to use the same string on both Unix and Windows very often — even when the 'same' program is available on both platforms.

Comment: In practice (i.e. disregarding what the standard has to say), `system` to execute basic commands is pretty portable within Linux distributions and Windows. Note that by basic I mean something equivalent to `system("command")`.

Comment: @Rapptz Not true; it's entirely possible for bashisms, differing filesystems, and environment differences (user aliases, etc) to grind basic commands into dust. This happens with frightening regularity.

Comment: @Alice Not... really. On Windows it's the equivalent of `cmd /c "command"`, on POSIX systems it's the equivalent of `sh -c 'command'`. If the `command` is available on both Windows and Linux then it should (and has) work totally fine. I know that `system` is seen as bad, but what you describe shouldn't happen in the basic case unless you're doing some extremely strange stuff (like possibly piping or querying the filesystem). Basically, as long as you avoid shell features you should be good to go and security risks as well.

Comment: @Alice Guys can't I just change one or two characters when I port to Windows? Like the Linux version could be `system("./a.out")` and then the Windows version could be `system("a.exe")`.

Comment: @Rapptz Yes, really. First, those claims are not true; the specification does not dictate what you have said. It's entirely allowed for system() to call the users shell rather than system shell; if one user runs dash and one runs bash, the command can easily be parsed differently. If aliases exist for one user but not for another, this can result in different commands being executed (remember, they probably don't know ahead of time what command you may be calling, so how would they know their alias is a bad idea?) system() only works fine until it doesn't.

Comment: @gragas Yes, if your idea of portability is exactly two computers you have tested it on. It is not portable between shells, between versions of shells, between OS's, versions of OS's, or even different users. If you want it to work on exactly two computers for sure, and possibly (but by no means certainly) many others, then yes, that can be done. But that's not generally what "portable" means.

Comment: There are two library based solutions that you could use. Boost.Process (not a boost library yet) (http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) and Poco.Process (http://pocoproject.org/documentation/index.html).

Comment: @gragas: Be aware that Alice's opinion on what `system` may do is not a majority opinion, and in particular is not shared by any existing implementor of `system`, be it Microsoft, IBM or GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is simply to synchronously execute a subprocess, `system` really isn't a bad bet. It is defined in C89, so it is highly portable, and the performance is not necessarily a problem unless you need to run a huge number of subprocesses.

Yes, you have to be aware of security issues: you should clear your environment variables and always be sure to execute the process using a full path (when possible) to avoid PATH attacks. Also, never use an external input when constructing your `system` command without the proper escaping.

If you are careful with it, it is a good, portable way to run external programs.

Comment: It is not portable; between windows and linux, the drastically different shell systems can cause hard to diagnose behaviors. Even between Dash and Bash, there are a whole list of errata to deal with. Only by using it in an extremely limited way (and taking note of any possible system differences) could it be used effectively. Hardly portable.

Comment: @Alice: And what would you propose that is more portable — and preferably standardized too?

Comment: It is more portable than literally any other approach. This is what I'm saying. If you want to forego portability, then of course I agree there are better alternatives to `system`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nothing I said in any way implied a more portable or standardized solution. There *is no portable solution*.

Comment: @nneonneo It is not portable, for the reasons outlined; there is no scale of portability here. It's simply not portable, and no solution exists that is in any way portable, because the problem *itself* is not portable; embedded systems often do not support this sort of access, and they are 90% of the microprocessor market.

Comment: @Alice: embedded systems are totally, completely separate beasts. One practically never writes fully portable code there - each processor has its own quirks. And the OP was pretty clearly not asking about embedded processors.

Comment: @nneonneo  He said portable, not "portable but only to x86 derived processors commonly used in desktop towers", which is what you seem to be implying he meant (as system() doesn't tend to work well on ARM systems used for smart phones, webos not withstanding). Saying "portable" and thinking he means "not actually all that portable" is a bit odd.

Comment: What the heck? system() works on iOS, [on Android](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/bionic/libc/unistd/system.c), and on any ARM box running usual GNU/Linux.

Comment: Agree with nneonneo. The question is tagged C++. That excludes 8051 microcontrollers and the ilk, embedded C++ is Linux/VxWorks and the like. They **all** have `system`, even embedded systems a LOT simpler than Android. Heck, even Symbian had `system` (in P.I.P.S. lib)

Comment: Having system does not mean the same *parameter* given to system will have the same *result*. It works but it does not have portable results. Different understandings of what "portable" means; you can surely execute system() portably, *but will it do what you want for non-trivial inputs?* On Android and iOS in particular, *not necessarily*.

Answer (score -3):

No; any such solution would *necessarily entail the same risks*. `system` is faulty explicitly because it requires a `string` parameter, and uses that to access an unknown (and not necessarily standardized) file system.

However, if you need to execute another executable *portably*, you have no other choice; there is no process concept in C/C++ (think about it; it's entirely acceptable to make a program that runs with no filesystem, no other executables, and even no other threads).

Here are some things you could do to make it *safer* to use:

1. Use the file system API from C++11 (or fopen if you want to be really portable) to check to see if the supplied file actually exists; system can execute shell code, which can be dangerous.
2. Do not add file system specific things to the string (such as "../"), because file systems are not portable. You should be okay if the program you want to execute is in the same directory as the currently executing one.
3. Use Posix (if windows portability cannot be assured), and use fork/exec. Then you have much more control.

[Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) may also be used if "portable" means "portable to a few specific platforms, not esoteric ones".

Comment: Careful with existence checks. It isn't trivial to protect against TOCTTOU attacks in a cross-platform way.

Comment: Also, Windows doesn't support POSIX. It sometimes supports a subset of POSIX, but compliance is definitely spotty. And Cygwin is not an ideal solution for portability.

Comment: @nneonneo It's impossible to use system with any degree of confidence anyway. And as I mentioned explicitly, "if windows portability cannot be assured".